# why cassandra some query is very slow on a small parition

Tags: cassandra

Apache Canssandra version 2.2.5

we have a cassandra cluster, which has 10 notes. The total data size is 10TB.  There is a very large table inbox. few queries on this table is very very slow. 95% query can return within 10ms. but few query read timeout ( > 5s ).

inbox table's schema is :

```
   CREATE TABLE feeds.inbox (
    owner_id bigint,
    activity_id bigint,
    insert_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (owner_id, activity_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activity_id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

one of the slow queries is this:

```
select activity_id, insert_time FROM inbox WHERE owner_id=87500212012802048 ORDER BY activity_id desc;
```

there is only 44 rows for this partition (owner_id=87500212012802048).

the query tracing:

```
activity                                                                                                                             | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                                                   Execute CQL3 query | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.970000 | 172.31.8.188 |              0
 Parsing select activity_id, insert_time FROM inbox WHERE owner_id=87500212012802048 ORDER BY activity_id desc; [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.971000 | 172.31.8.188 |            147
                                                                                            Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.971000 | 172.31.8.188 |            213
                                                                                reading data from /172.31.8.187 [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.971000 | 172.31.8.188 |            369
                                                      Sending READ message to /172.31.8.187 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.31.8.187] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.971000 | 172.31.8.188 |            739
                                                   READ message received from /172.31.8.188 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.31.8.188] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.972000 | 172.31.8.187 |             19
                                                                      Executing single-partition query on inbox [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.972000 | 172.31.8.187 |            350
                                                                                   Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.972000 | 172.31.8.187 |            372
                                                                                    Merging memtable tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.972000 | 172.31.8.187 |            414
                                                                    Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 353339 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.972000 | 172.31.8.187 |            446
                                                                               Key cache hit for sstable 353313 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.972000 | 172.31.8.187 |            467
                                                              Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.972001 | 172.31.8.187 |            475
                                                                    Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 352862 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.973000 | 172.31.8.187 |            590
                                                                               Key cache hit for sstable 352122 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.973000 | 172.31.8.187 |            612
                                                              Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.973000 | 172.31.8.187 |            621
                                                                               Key cache hit for sstable 345513 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.973000 | 172.31.8.187 |            779
                                                              Seeking to partition indexed section in data file [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.973000 | 172.31.8.187 |            820
                                      Skipped 0/5 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.973000 | 172.31.8.187 |            837
                                                                     Merging data from memtables and 3 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:53.973001 | 172.31.8.187 |            848
                                                                             Read 44 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:57.546000 | 172.31.8.187 |         574196
                                                                            Enqueuing response to /172.31.8.188 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:57.549000 | 172.31.8.187 |         577130
                                          Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /172.31.8.188 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.31.8.188] | 2016-05-04 20:58:57.551000 | 172.31.8.187 |         579411
                                       REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /172.31.8.187 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.31.8.187] | 2016-05-04 20:58:57.557000 | 172.31.8.188 |         586750
                                                                         Processing response from /172.31.8.187 [SharedPool-Worker-4] | 2016-05-04 20:58:57.557000 | 172.31.8.188 |         586930
                                                                                                                     Request complete | 2016-05-04 20:58:57.560568 | 172.31.8.188 |         590568
```

we can see that the step 'Read 44 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-4]' take more then 50s!. why the query is so slow, although there is only 44 rows in this partition.

when i change clustering key query order to asc, the query boost a little, still too slow for online functions.

```
     activity                                                                                                                            | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                                                  Execute CQL3 query | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275000 | 172.31.8.188 |              0
 Parsing select activity_id, insert_time FROM inbox WHERE owner_id=87500212012802048 ORDER BY activity_id asc; [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275000 | 172.31.8.188 |             96
                                                                                           Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275000 | 172.31.8.188 |            150
                                                                     Executing single-partition query on inbox [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275000 | 172.31.8.188 |            393
                                                                                  Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275000 | 172.31.8.188 |            419
                                                                                   Merging memtable tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275000 | 172.31.8.188 |            450
                                                         Partition index lookup allows skipping sstable 324509 [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275001 | 172.31.8.188 |            510
                                                                              Key cache hit for sstable 324457 [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275001 | 172.31.8.188 |            534
                                                                   Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275001 | 172.31.8.188 |            546
                                                                              Key cache hit for sstable 324018 [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275001 | 172.31.8.188 |            640
                                                                   Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.275001 | 172.31.8.188 |            685
                                                                              Key cache hit for sstable 321829 [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.276000 | 172.31.8.188 |            899
                                                                   Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.276000 | 172.31.8.188 |            926
                                                                              Key cache hit for sstable 314770 [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.276000 | 172.31.8.188 |           1171
                                                                   Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.276000 | 172.31.8.188 |           1199
                                     Skipped 0/5 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.276000 | 172.31.8.188 |           1456
                                                                    Merging data from memtables and 4 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.276000 | 172.31.8.188 |           1488
                                                                            Read 44 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.440000 | 172.31.8.188 |         165319
                                                                                                                    Request complete | 2016-05-04 21:19:29.448062 | 172.31.8.188 |         173062
```

Comment: whats the schema for `inbox` ? Are there any really large cells in it?

Comment: if you are using no of tokens per node is 1 then it will create problem always .Because cassandra is not able to distribute load equally to every node. So you have to use no of tokens per node 256 . In case of 1 token if reading and writing happening on same node then it will give slow result .

Comment: @ChrisLohfink there is no large cells in it. only owner_id(long), actor_id(long) and insert_time(date)

Comment: @mahendrasingh I am using virtual nodes. 256 tokens per node.

Answer (score 0):

From the trace log, we can see that those 44 rows are stored across 4 sstables.

> Merging data from memtables and 4 sstables

Can you try compacting the `inbox` column family? This should reduce the time to read.

But I am afraid that this wouldn't help the situation.

> Merging data from memtables and 4 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-3] | 1488
>
> Read 44 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-3]   |       165319

Can you append the Cassnadra log for further inspection. It seems that some other process is taking a lot of time after merge and before read.

Comment: thank you for answer. what kind of logs should i append? there is little info in system.log. and a mass of logs in debug.log file. I can not find related items from the debug.log.

Comment: Hi @chaitan64arun. I take a stack trace when executing query.  It seems, the thread is doing this for a long time: "SharedPool-Worker-5" #221 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f177517a000 nid=0x8b6 runnable [0x00007f1471e5b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RangeTombstoneList.addInternal(RangeTombstoneList.java:689)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RangeTombstoneList.insertFrom(RangeTombstoneList.java:649)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RangeTombstoneList.add(RangeTombstoneList.java:170)